# using multple resource overlays in android

Tags: android

I tried home building the whole android tree for my device.

My case is that my device tree depends on some other common tree which has it's own overlay directory. Coincidentally I need to edit some option in one  file which is present on the common tree's overlay directory.

To do this, I tried creating a copy of the overlay directory and made the edits there then added something like this after line where I've included the common tree:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS := device/vendor/phone/overlay
```

After building the OS, I found out that the options I've edited are not used instead, the common tree's options are.

Could anyone shed light on why my edits are ignored?